# Where/How are the XDG_*_DIR user directory variables supposed to be set?

Tags: xdg, xdg-user-dirs

I'm referring to: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

I have the following files in my `.config` directory:

`~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
# ...
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/downloads"
# ... there are only comments in this file, except the line above ...
```

(I guess this file needs to be sourced somewhere? But where and how?)

`~/.config/user-dirs.conf`:

```
enabled=False
```

(This file seems to be necesseary to prevent `xdg-user-dirs-update` from overwriting `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.)

However, **`$XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR` is not set when I run a shell.**

**Where/How are the XDG***DIR user directory variables supposed to be set?**

Am I supposed to source `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in one of the files sourced by my login shell (e.g. in `.bash_profile`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set it this way

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOADS ${HOME}/Downloads;
```

update all xdg dirs

```
xdg-user-dirs-update;

source ${HOME}/.config/user-dirs.dirs;
```

Comment: ```source ${HOME}/.config/user-dirs.dirs```  in ```.bash_profile```?

Comment: as you want in .bashrc for terminal sessions (interactive shell) or /and inside scripts , yes you should source it in all cases !
OR  this way to get a specific var `xdg-user-dir DOWNLOADS`